# mysql database name and credentials inside docker container not updating

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin, lamp

I have a **LAMP** stack with laravel setup in **docker-compose** containers,everything seems to be working fine so far. I initially had a test database with the name of **homestead** setup in **docker-compose.yml** that was just there for testing now i want to change it to something more meaningful like my project name. let me show you my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

networks:
  laravel:

services:
  site:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: nginx.dockerfile
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
    networks:
      - laravel

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.29
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: alis
      MYSQL_USER: alis
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
    networks:
      - laravel
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql      
      

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    networks:
      - laravel

  composer:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: composer.dockerfile
    container_name: composer
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - php
    user: laravel
    entrypoint: ['composer', '--ignore-platform-reqs']
    networks:
      - laravel

  npm:
    image: node:latest
    container_name: npm
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
      - 3001:3001
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    entrypoint: ['npm']
    networks:
      - laravel

  artisan:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: php.dockerfile
    container_name: artisan
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html:delegated
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    user: laravel
    entrypoint: ['php', '/var/www/html/artisan']
    networks:
      - laravel
      
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always 
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    depends_on: 
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
    networks:
      - laravel
```

the problem is **phpmyadmin** is still using the old database and credentials , it tried the following solutions

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose down -v
```

then

```
docker-compose up -d
```

this didnt work.Out of frustration even thought this is probably not the best way to do it, I removed all containers, all images and then ran

```
docker-compose up -d
```

to re-install everything from scratch to my surprise phpmyadmin still picks up the old database config.Does anyone know the reason for this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Your phpmyadmin service tries to connect as root:secret (`MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`) while your `mysql` service defines root:pass (`MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD`) as admin user.

See the available configuration here:

https://hub.docker.com/_/phpmyadmin
https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

Comment: thanks @jonas for your comment, i'm still a bit confused about the issue, can you please elaborate?

Comment: In your `phpmyadmin` service definition, set `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass` instead of `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret`